# Constructing a predictive parser table for this grammar: ​E:=EE+/EE-/num

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

I have removed the left recursion and left factoring, now the grammar looks like this:

```
E :=num E''  
E'':=EE'E''/epsilon  
E':=+/-.
```

But I am stuck in finding the FOLLOW(E'') and thus cannot further proceed with the problem.
I am learning by myself so please help me if I am making any conceptual mistake.

Comment: Is this input for some program?

Comment: @Marichyasana I didn't get your question. This is not an input for a program it's just an LL(1) grammar with production rules. And I have to construct a parsing table for it, which in turn checks whether the input is syntactically correct or wrong.

Comment: E'' can only be at the end of the sentence, so if you are using an augmented grammar its FOLLOW set is `{$}` (or whatever you use for the end token).